# Checking for end of file does not work as expected

Tags: java, file, io

I try to check if I have reached the end of my file, but the condition with empty string does not work

```
public void readEquation(String fileName) {  
        File aFile = new File(fileName);
        String line = null;
        int cnt = 0;
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(aFile);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {      
                //but line gets null
                intoMap(line, cnt);
                cnt++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does not work now? `line` should never be `null` in the while block.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Use the source code as the file to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are erroneously reading two lines instead of one a time. The condition of the loop reads a line by itself and then you read another one inside the loop. I suggest this change:

```
public void readEquation(String fileName) {  
        File aFile = new File(fileName);
        String line = null;
        int cnt = 0;
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(aFile);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {                  
                intoMap(line, cnt);
                cnt++;
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading two lines in succession: one in the loop condition, then another in the body of the loop. The one you read in the condition is ignored and never used. Nothing ever checks the value of the second line.

Usually people write this loop this way:

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {      
    intoMap(line, cnt);
    cnt++;
}
```

This way you always check the line before using it.

Comment: @Den-Ben -- I respectfully suggest that you try again, because if this is the case, then you must have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {      
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();    //but line gets null
```

You read two lines here.

To avoid that use tmp String like

```
String line=null;
while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {  
    //now line stores line from file or null if file doesn't have new line
```

Edit - example

I just tested this code

```
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;
    try {
        String line = null;
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\ranks.txt"));
        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {      
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and it worked.

Comment: @Den-Ben: "*does not work*" is **far** to vague. You must be more specific.

Comment: @Den-Ben have you tried to print your lines in console to determine when the "does not work" part happens? Or maybe tell us what you expect from algorithm and what id does in reality.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that when you execute bufferedReader.readLine() in your while condition, you are already reading the line.

You should do this:

```
public void readEquation(String fileName) {  
    File aFile = new File(fileName);
    String line = null;
    int cnt = 0;
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(aFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {       // only reads once
            intoMap(line, cnt);
            cnt++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
 while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {      

                    intoMap(line, cnt);
                    cnt++;
                }
```